# Updating Ruby and Gem on Fedora Core 8

Tags: fedora, ruby

I have a new Fedora Core 8 image I am using (I am doing this on the EC2 -- Amazon Web Services).

The image has Ruby 1.8.6 and gem 1.2

When I try to update Ruby using yum or gem using 'gem update --system' it tells me there is no update.  Howevewr, I know that there is 1.8.7 for Ruby and 1.3 for gem.

Why is this?
What is the best thing for me to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi hortitude, and welcome to Super User! Although this question is about advanced computer… stuff (that a super user would use), it *may* be better suited for ServerFault.com, seeing that it is more about **server** configuration than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is quite old, but its still unanswered too, so for the sake of newcomer rubyist:

first step of installing anything on Fedora is to upgrade it to Ubuntu :)

Great Debian/Ubuntu AMIs aere referenced at http://alestic.com/

You will solve yourself a lot of administration pain.

It wont solve the Ruby pain though as Debian is a brain damaged with regards to Ruby/Gems.

there are a couple of things you can do though (on both debian/ubuntu and fedora)

I posted an Ubuntu AMI bootstrap script from an oss project I'm working on at http://gist.github.com/307730

Not everything there is relevant to you but I've burned my hand so typing singlehandedly :), can't do much editing. its structured and I hope is easy to understand.

another thing you can try is installing rvm (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) I'm considering adopting it myself as a proper multi-distro solution to ruby pains.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the RPMs, then you're probably locked into a specific version from Fedora. However, you should consider upgrading to a newer Fedora. Version 8 was released November 8, 2007; two years in the Ruby world is like 5-10 years anywhere else.